# Excecute subprocess.Popen() from VSCode to open another instance of VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, subprocess, popen

I am using the following line of code to open VS Code (regular version) from Spyder or VS Code Insiders:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/code.exe"])
```

It works perfectly fine this way.

However, if I want to execute the line from VS Code to open another instance of VS Code, it does not work. Meaning, it basically does nothing.

I only works when I modify it as follows:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["code"], shell=True)
```

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `--new-window` flag, otherwise VS Code is probably reusing the running instance.